# Custom Image in React Native Navigation 5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a navigation:

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const TabNavigator = () => (
    <NavigationContainer theme={navigationTheme}>
        <Tab.Navigator tabBarOptions={{
            showLabel: false,
        }}>
            <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{tabBarIcon: <Image style={{width:22, height:22}} source = {require('../../assets/location.png')} />}} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Search" component={ProfileNavigator} options={{tabBarIcon: props => <SimpleLineIcons name="people" size={24} color="black" />}}/>
            <Tab.Screen name="Messages" component={MessagesScreen} options={{tabBarIcon: props => <AntDesign name="message1" size={24} color="black" />}} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsNavigator} options={{tabBarIcon: props => <SimpleLineIcons name="settings" size={24} color="black" />}} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
)
```

Im trying to use a custom image on the first Tab which is causing the error:

```
<Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{tabBarIcon: <Image style={{width:22, height:22}} source = {require('../../assets/location.png')} />}} />
```

This works fine:

```
<Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsNavigator} options={{tabBarIcon: props => <SimpleLineIcons name="settings" size={24} color="black" />}} />
```

This is the error:

```
TypeError: renderIcon is not a function. (In 'renderIcon({
      focused: true,
      size: size,
      color: activeTintColor
    })', 'renderIcon' is an instance of Object)
```

The issue is im trying to use custom images for my tab bar icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing your Image component to tabBarIcon Prop like this

```
<Tab.Screen
  name={"Home"}
  component={HomeScreen}
  options={{
    tabBarIcon: () => {
      return <Image style={styles.icon} source={require('../../assets/location.png'} />
    }
  }}
/>
```

for more details on tabBar Props: [Docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#props)